# SQL simplified group by and average (flatten rows aggregation based on multiple columns)

Tags: mysql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have three tables that are all linked through an "id" column. When all three joined, it looks somewhat like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+
| id | Color | T1Data | distinct_value    | T3_data |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+
|  1 | green | ab     | A                 |      10 |
|  1 | green | ab     | A                 |      20 |
|  1 | green | ab     | B                 |     100 |
|  1 | green | ab     | B                 |     200 |
|  2 | blue  | xz     | A                 |      30 |
|  2 | blue  | xz     | A                 |      40 |
|  2 | blue  | xz     | B                 |     300 |
|  2 | blue  | xz     | B                 |     400 |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+
```

Currently I'm just `SELECTING` the columns, averaging (`AVG`) the T3 data, and `GROUP BY` every column preceding the data:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.Color, T1Data, T2.distinct_value, avg(T3_data)
from T1 
left join T2 on T1.id = T2.id
left join T3 on (T3.id = T2.id and T3.distinct_value = T2.distinct_value)
group by T1.id, T1.Color, T1.Data, T2.distinct_value
order by T1.id;
```

This is the result:

```
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+
| id | Color | T1Data | T2_distinct value | avg     |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+
|  1 | green | ab     | A                 |      15 |
|  1 | green | ab     | B                 |     150 |
|  2 | blue  | xz     | A                 |      35 |
|  2 | blue  | xz     | B                 |     350 |
+----+-------+--------+-------------------+---------+
```

Which is the desired outcome. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to call the aggregation data? The `Color` and `T1Data` columns are strings and will all be identical for the same id. **However, I'd like to not have as many `group by` statements as I have columns preceding the averaged T3_data. Is there a way to `group by` just `id` and `distinct_value` that will produce the same output?**

Comment: Well this looks pretty good to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If you have MySQL 5.7.5 or newer, then you may omit `color` and `t1data` fields from the group by list, since they are functionally dependent on the `t1.id` field. See mysql manual on [handling group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers.
>
> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence.

If you have an earlier mysql versìon, then you can still use mysql's special aggregation function [any_value()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value):

> This function is useful for GROUP BY queries when the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled, for cases when MySQL rejects a query that you know is valid for reasons that MySQL cannot determine. The function return value and type are the same as the return value and type of its argument, but the function result is not checked for the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode.

The 3rd solution is obviously disabling the only full group by sql mode, but I would not recommend that.

Comment: That's a very helpful answer. I looked at the any_value() doc. I'm not sure it will help. If a non-aggregated column (Color for example) is not included in the group by statement, the error is: `Invalid operation: column "t1.color" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;
1 statement failed.`

Comment: I do not really have anything to add to my answer. These are the 3 options you have, use the one you can based on your mysql version and fitness for your purpose. The documentation on any_value() has sample code for your use and detailed explanation.